# Wrong character encoding with FreeTDS connection to sql server

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, odbc, freetds, rodbc

I want to access mssql server from R through freetds. I used RODBC library and I set up the connection. However, I have a problem with encoding. Serbian characters appear as \u009, \u008, etc.

The server has SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation while my system is UTF-8. I tried adding ClientCharset=UTF-8;ServerCharset=CP1252; to the odbc.ini, but the output from a mssql query doesn't change. The version of my sql server is 12.

I tried looking online but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's my odbc.ini:

```
[srvnm]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=ODBC FreeTDS
Server= myserverip
Port=1433
ReadOnly=Yes
TDS_Version=7.4
ServerCharset=CP1252
ClientCharset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you include your `freetds.conf` as well?